How to prove/show upper-hemicontinuity of Correspondences
I have some troubles proving/showing upper-hemicontinuity for some rather simple correspondences:
Let $\varphi:[0,1] \rightarrow[0,1]$ be the correspondence defined by
$$
\varphi(x)= \begin{cases}{[0, x]} & \text { if } 0 \leq x<\frac{1}{2} \\ {[0,1]} & \text { if } \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1\end{cases}
$$
(a) Is $\varphi$ upper-hemicontinuous? Is $\varphi$ lower-hemicontinuous?
(b) Show that the function $m:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $m(x)=\max _{y \in \varphi(x)} y$ is not continuous. Which condition in Berge's maximum theorem is violated in this problem?
My solutions
a1) Yes $\varphi$ is uhc, let $x \in[0, 1]$ and $B$ an open set such that $\varphi (x) \in B$, then $\varphi (x') \subset \varphi (x) $ when $x' \leq x$ and thus $\varphi (x') \subset B$, $x' \in A$ where A is a neighborhood of $x$.
Is this a correct proof? Can I prove this using the theorem of a closed graph of $\varphi$ ?
a2) No, $\varphi$ is not lhc at $x=1 / 2$ since $\varphi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=[0,1] \bigcap B \neq \varnothing$
for $B=\left(\frac{3}{4}, 1\right)$ while $x=\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$ gives $\varphi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon\right) \bigcap B=\varnothing \operatorname{since} \varphi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon\right)=\left[0, \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon\right]$. Hence not lhc.
b)
Since $\varphi$ is not lhc, $\varphi$ is not continuous and Berge's maximum theorem is violated. But how can I show it?
Thanks for all input, I'm rather new to proofs.
Best, TS
